# React: Change width of progress bar from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the width of my progress bar to change depending on the input percentage. So if you submit a number using the button the h4 changes but not yet the width of my progress bar. How do I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
function Progress() {

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="top-menu">
                <div>
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="progress-container">
                <h4>Progress: {progress} %</h4>
                <div className="progress-bar" style={width%}></div>
            </div>

            <div className="inputs">
                <label>Progress (in %)</label>
                <div className="input">
                    <form onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const { value } = e.target.progress;
                        setProgress(value);
                        e.target.progress.value = '';
                    }}>
                        <input id="progress" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 75"></input>
                        <button type="submit" className="button">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

  }
```

Comment: {width: progress/100*my_max_width_value}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` prop you are passing to the `progress-bar` div is not valid.

The `style` prop on a `div` is an object with property names as the keys. So you should instead be trying something like:

```
<div classname="progress-bar" style={ { width: `${progress}%` } }></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works as you wanted:

```
<div className="progress-container">
    <h4>Progress: {progress} %</h4>
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", height: "3rem" }}>
      <div
        className="progress-bar"
        style={{
          width: `${progress}%`,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```